# Avoiding integers multiplication overflow for 3+ integers

Tags: c++, c++11, integer-overflow

I'm testing my C++11 code with static analysis tool (CodeSonar).

Here's my code:

```
int weights_size = c * n * size * size;
int weights_memory_size = weights_size * sizeof(float);
if (IS_OVERFLOW_6(weights_memory_size, c, n, size, size, (int)sizeof(float))) {
    overflow_error();
}

l.weights = (float*) calloc(weights_size, sizeof(float));
```

Here's my code of integer overflow check macro:

```
#define IS_OVERFLOW_6(multipliedVal, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5)  (((val1) > 0) && ((val2) > 0) && ((val3) > 0) && ((val4) > 0) && ((val5) > 0) && ((multipliedVal) > 0) && ((val1) == (((((multipliedVal) / (val2)) / (val3)) / (val4)) / (val5))) ? false : true)
```

This macro worked fine for checking multiplications of two integers (the macro IS_OVERFLOW_3, which is defined as

```
(((val1) > 0) && ((val2) > 0) && ((multipliedVal) > 0) && ((val1) == ((multipliedVal) / (val2))) ? false : true)
```

'worked fine' means CodeSonar tool didn't complain.

However, the static analysis tool still complain about IS_OVERFLOW_6 checks. that is, the tool claims that there could be a case that passes the check but the multiplication still overflow.

Is the check insufficient? or is the static analysis tool wrong?

Comment: it looks to me like overflow of signed integers is happening here, which is undefined behavior. Switch to unsigneds, instead.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The check includes positiveness of all arguments.

Comment: It’s about the *types*, not the values. Unsigned integer type overflow is defined, signed is not.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Um, I added typecasts to my macro (put (unsigned int) in front of arguments) but CodeSonar still complains.. Maybe the tool is doing wrong.

Comment: You cannot check overflow **afterward**, as you will got already UB in case of overflow. You have to test it before the overflow occurs and avoid it.

Comment: What are you expecting to get from the `*sizeof(float)` ?  or `*4`, as the rest of us say?